# Función guardar y ver datos en PHP

Tags: php

Necesito hacer una aplicación que almacene en un archivo txt una lista con nombres y apellidos y que al pulsar el botón "ver datos" los muestre. Alguna idea.

Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
introducir el código aquí

<?php
//Declaro los textos que van a usar los botones de los submits
const GUARDAR = 'Guardar';
const VER_DATOS = 'Ver datos';
//Inicializo las variables que contienen los valores de los inputs a null en caso de que no se haya enviado el formulario aún
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];


$datos = array("nombre" => $nombre, "apellido" => $apellido);
//Si el metodo de la solicitud es un post es decir si se envio el formulario y la operacion tiene algun valor
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['operacion'])){
  //Si la operacion es la de guardar.....
  if($_POST['operacion'] === GUARDAR){
      //Abro el archivo para escribir
      $file = @fopen("datos.txt", "a");
      //Creo un arreglo con los valores que voy a guardar
      $data = ['nombre' => $nombre, 'apellido' => $apellido]; 

      //Guardo el arreglo codificado a json
      fwrite($file, json_encode($data));
      //Cierro el archivo
      fclose($file);

      $nombre = null;
      $apellido = null;
  } else {
      //Si la operacion es la de Cargar o ver y el archivo existe
      if(file_exists('datos.txt')){
          //Almaceno el contenido completo del archivo en esta variable
          $content = file_get_contents('datos.txt');
          //Decodifico el contenido almacenado en formato json
          $decoded = json_decode($content);
          //Asigno los valores traidos del archivo

         $nombre = $decoded->nombre;
         $apellido = $decoded->apellido;

      }
  }
}

//Cuerpo de la página
$body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <FORM method="post" name="formulario" autocomplete="off">
    Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="'.$nombre.'">

    Apellido: <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" value="'.$apellido.'">

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="'.GUARDAR.'" name="operacion">
    <input type="submit" value="'.VER_DATOS.'" name="operacion">

    </FORM>
    </body>
    </html>';

echo $body;
echo "se ha guardado   ";
     echo $nombre." ".$apellido. "!";
?>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

El problema es:

> no consigo que me guarde en el fichero y me lo lea por pantalla al
>   pulsar el botón ver datos

Comment: bienvenido a la comunidad, te comento que nosotros funcionamos tu colocando tus dudas de código y mostrando que haz tratado y alguien seguramente te apoyará; pero solo llegar y pedir que se te haga no va a servir; mira [ask]

Comment: y de ese código que nos puedes comentar? fallos? funciona? que le hace falta?

Comment: no consigo que me guarde en el fichero y me lo lea por pantalla al pulsar el botón ver datos

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no le estas diciendo que muestres los datos.
La funcion `fgets` lee un fichero linea por linea.

```
<?php
//a partir de aquí viene lo que tú escribiste

//Si la operacion es la de Cargar o ver y el archivo existe
//esto muestra que existe, pero NO lo muestra
if(file_exists('datos.txt')){

  // muestra una lista de los datos guardados en el txt

  $ar = fopen("datos.txt","r") or die("No se pudo abrir el archivo");
  while (!feof($ar)){
  $linea = fgets($ar);
  $lineasalto = nl2br($linea);
  echo $lineasalto;
}
fclose($ar);
/*
      //Almaceno el contenido completo del archivo en esta variable
      $content = file_get_contents('datos.txt');

      //Decodifico el contenido almacenado en formato json
      $decoded = json_decode($content);
      //Asigno los valores traidos del archivo

     $nombre = $decoded->nombre;
     $apellido = $decoded->apellido;
*/
}
?>
```

Si lo pruebas asi, muestra los datos guardados en el txt.

Comment: siempre considera por favor explicar mejor el código que pones pues le debe servir a todos los que consulten tu respuesta saludos

Comment: ese código no resuelve mi duda,

Comment: alguien puede decirme alguna indicación?

Comment: disculpa, pero que indicación estas buscando?

Comment: necesito que me muestre todos los nombres y apellidos guardados al pulsar el boton verdatos

Comment: entiendo y lo que modifique hace que muestre todo lo que esta escrito en el txt. Lo probaste?